# Можно ли при перечислении использовать точку с запятой вместо запятой и при этом ещё и обобщение, следующее через тире?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире, перечисление, точка-с-запятой

Скажите, можно ли использовать точку с запятой для отделения перечислений в сочетании с обобщением, которое следует через тире? Есть какое-либо правило на этот счёт? Просто, если перечисляются сложные конструкции, запятая для отделения перечисляемого смешивается при чтении с прочими запятыми (уточняющие обороты, причастные обороты и пр.), и читать такое сложно. Точка же с запятой логично разделяет все эти сложные части, но тогда встаёт вопрос: а тире в таком случае и обобщение уместны? Меня интересует этот вопрос именно в теории, потому что всегда можно разбить на несколько предложений.

*В Берлине; в Париже, где бывала его сестра и гуляла по Елисейским; в Вене, городе театров и музеев, столице культуры; в Белграде; в Мадриде; в Риме, прекрасном Риме, великом городе великих людей, — всюду он побывал и всюду ему было до смерти скучно.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точки с запятыми [могут использоваться](http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg30.php), если однородные члены сильно распространены.
Какого-то особого правила про тире перед обощающим словом на этот случай я не встречал.
Полагаю очевидным, что использование таких конструкций ничуть не противоречит ни букве, ни духу правила про тире перед обобщающим словом, поскольку точка с запятой в перечислении — это просто "усиленная запятая", знак, функционально синонимичный запятой, используется просто для наглядности.